# Scraping JSON link is not working using fromJSON(url)

Tags: r, json, web-scraping

For web scraping I normally use the `jsonlite::fromJSON(url)` command which usually does the job for me. However this time it is inside another text.
Basically like this:

```
jQuery([ 
JSON stuff that I am more used to 
]);
```

How do I get around this easily?
The actual data looks like this when I call the address (I have tapped it more pretty):

```
jQuery(
[
{"Date":"2019-05-31T00:00:00+02:00","FromTime":"2019-05-31T00:00:00+02:00","ToTime":"2019-05-31T00:15:00+02:00","Value":3315.9120000000003,"Value2":2584.244,"Value3":731.668},
{"Date":"2019-05-31T00:00:00+02:00","FromTime":"2019-05-31T00:15:00+02:00","ToTime":"2019-05-31T00:30:00+02:00","Value":3386.238,"Value2":2655.814,"Value3":730.424}
]
);
```

The errormessage I get when I try to make the function parse it is

```
Error in parse_con(txt, bigint_as_char) : 
  lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       jQuery([{"Date":"2019-05-29T00:
                     (right here) ------^
```

End goal is just to have a dataframe to continue work on.

Comment: I don't understand what the question is. What's inside the `jQuery` function is valid JSON—[test it yourself](https://jsonlint.com/). Where does `jQuery` come from, and what are you using it for?

Comment: @camille thank you for answering it says 
```Error in parse_con(txt, bigint_as_char) : 
  lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       jQuery
                     (right here) ------^
```

Comment: It's unclear until you include some code. jQuery is a javascript library, so I'm not sure what you're doing with it here or where it comes from

Comment: @camille
This is literally all I use to do before manipulating with the data :) 
```library(jsonlite)
Raw<-fromJSON("https://ws.50hertz.com/web02/api/PhotovoltaicActual/ListRecords?filterDateTime=2019-05-30T22:23:14.716Z&callback=jQuery&_=1559254994256")```

Comment: Is there an API you're working with? That URL has jQuery as a callback but I'm not sure why. I suppose one thing you could do is try to just read what comes back from that URL as a string, not convert it from JSON immediately, and remove the jQuery function, *then* parse it. But if there are docs for the API or wherever you're getting this from, I'd start there

Comment: @camille thanks a lot. To look at it as a string and delete the "extra", that could actually be a way. sadly no documentation. Just if you can answer it easily. Do you know how to get it down as a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can substr what you want from rvest return. It looks like jquery return will have start and end syntax

```
library(rvest)
library(jsonlite)

url <- 'https://ws.50hertz.com/web02/api/PhotovoltaicActual/ListRecords?filterDateTime=2019-05-30T22:23:14.716Z&callback=jQuery&_=1559254994256'
r <- read_html(url) %>%
  html_node("p") %>% 
  html_text() 

x <- jsonlite::fromJSON(substr(r[1], 8, nchar(r) - 2))
```